# StringFormat does not work in code-behind binding(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

Here is the xaml part.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <Label x:Name="TestLabel"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TestTextBox"
                 Text="initial"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the code-behind part.

```
TestLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Text")
            {
                Source = TestTextBox,
                StringFormat = "This is the textbox text: {0}"
            });
```

Binding works fine. When I write something to textbox, label content updates immediately. But StringFormat seems does not have any effect at all. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Set the Label's ContentStringFormat.